# Could not restrict app to Landscape mode in just iOS 5 for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, orientation

I am working on iPad app, which I restricted just onto Landscape (Right and Left) in info.plist file and also Project settings. This works fine for iOS 6 and 7 but this not working fine in iOS 5 when device move to portrait (app move to portrait also). I googled and then added code.
in App delegate:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window  // iOS 6 autorotation fix
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

in each View controller.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

But alas, still same issue facing. I googled too much but couldn't any help. Kindly guide me on this. How to accomplish this task. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution but man, iOS5? I'm trying to wrap my head around a business case for supporting iOS5...

Comment: Sorry for late reply, This issue was just in iOS 5 which I handled kindly see my answer below and read carefully. Hope you get answer. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I saw it was iOS5. I'm just trying to understand WHY you need to support iOS5

Comment: Because this is my app requirement to support iOS5 and also this only creating issue in iOS5.

Comment: I absolutely understand it is your requirement. I'm trying to understand WHY it is your requirement. This is more a business question than a tech question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I found Solution.**

I am using "SWRevealViewController" Third party library for Sidebar separate view like iPhone Facebook app has, and this class is the starting point of my project. I set Landscape in "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" on every class in my project RevealView Controller which is my root class, and in this class orientation is set for all. Now I feel relief after restricting to landscape in this class also. Cheers.